# Warnings from bluebird promises in Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've read about the new warnings regarding [Promises not returning from handlers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it) and had a related question...

In some of my unit tests, I stub out the functionality of certain dependencies to return promises using Jasmine's spyOn function. So with this new change, I am seeing quite a few warnings when my tests run. I can of course disable the warnings, but I wondered if there was an improved approach I could use that would naturally get rid of such errors?

Example:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {

  var formatter = new Formatter();
  var promise = Promise.resolve(['1,000', '2.45']);

  spyOn(formatter, 'format').and.returnValue(promise);

  // internally calls formatter.format()
  doStuff(formatter, [1000, 2.4567]).then(done);

 // promise is not returned
});
```

Can add a full working plunker if that would be of use?

Comment: Would `return`ing the promise instead of passing around `done` callbacks work? Then you should do that.

Comment: Are you talking about returning `doStuff()...`? If so, I still believe you see the warning since `promise` is not being returned.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `done` callback of jasmine [does not](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/dbd198f7d0b0d43b8064113b0e1354febc6bebb2/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L1946) return anything, so when you do `.then(done)` you trigger bluebird's warning for [a promise was created in a handler but none were returned from it](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it).

I solved this by adding a new method to the Promise object:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.prototype.jasmineDone = function(done) {
    return this.then(function() {
        done();
        return null;
    }, function(err) {
        done.fail(err);
        return null;
    });
};
```

Then I refactor my specs from (which triggers the warning):

```
 it('should ...', function(done) {
    doSomething().then(done, done.fail);
 });
```

To:

```
 it('should ...', function(done) {
    doSomething().jasmineDone(done);
 });
```